# Player must places the object in the preset position

Tags: unity, 2d

I want to know how to do like this video:
https://youtu.be/6gouxqSxeG8
At the minute 3:09, the player can put the street vendor in the predetermined location (with the green arrow show that place).

Please tell me some keyword about this or video tutorial about how to implement it in unity 2d.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is never just one solution for a problem in Unity. But I would approach this problem as follows:

1. Add a collider to each "drop zone".
2. When the player selects an object to place, create a sprite and make it follow the mouse cursor. You can use [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) to convert a mouse position to a world position.
3. When the player clicks, use [`Camera.ViewportPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportPointToRay.html) to get a ray which you can then feed into [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to detect the collider under the player's mouse cursor. You might want to use [layer masks](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) to restrict the raycast to drop zones only (improves performance and avoids hits with objects you didn't want).
4. When the raycast finds a drop zone (and not perhaps some other object which is in the way), replace the drop zone with a new instance of your street vendor prefab. Place the prefab at the coordinates of the drop zone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I show the area in which the player can place an object, like the green area with an arrow above? And if I want to expand more and more slot in the next "street" like that video, what should I do. Thanks again.

Comment: Those green areas could be done by adding a sprite renderer to the drop zone objects which have a partly alpha-transparent sprite. Your second question is very complex and depends on how you structured your project. You might want to ask that as a new question.